# How to show console.log results on VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, console.log

Okay I'm not sure what's the best way to phrase this question but how do I get the results from my console.log (line 14) to show up on the console/terminal? I'm hoping to see the results of random rgb generated for each col every time I click the button but it's not showing logs unfortunately.

[image]

Comment: Alternate take - how about looking in the devtools console? this is a client side console.log

Answer (score 0):

**Using console.log() debugging in Visual Studio Code**

**Step 1**: Create a folder and call it consoledebug
**Step 2**: Start Visual Studio Code, choose “open” – select that folder
**Step 3**: Select New File, call it index.html
**Step 4**: Add some HTML/JS and save it
**Step 5**: Select the “Run and Debug” icon and press the “Run and Debug” button

> For More Informations Visit :
> https://christianheilmann.com/2021/07/30/using-console-log-debugging-in-visual-studio-code/